# How to solve in RMarkdown pdf error related with complex centered subtitle

Tags: r, rmarkdown

I am working with RMardown and I am trying to add a centred subtitle containg model syntax that I am going to show at that section

````
---
title: "example"
author: "X"
date: "2023-09-23"
output: pdf_document
---

\newcommand{\csubsubsection}[1]{
  \hypertarget{#1}{%
  \subsubsection{\texorpdfstring{\centering\emph{#1}}{#1}}\label{#1}}
}

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

below after some sections....


## *Title*

\csubsubsection{Model applied: lm(x ~ y,random = ~ 1|A)}
````

However I am getting this error.

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.23 ...x ~ y, random = ~ 1|A)}}{section*.4}{}}
```

How could I solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Do you want all subsubsections centred or only some of them?

Comment: Not all subsection. Just when needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The hypertarget around the subsection is neither necessary nor useful, you can link to the subsection via the label.
- You should not use your whole subsection title as label. Choose a simple string, which you can remember. You should avoid special characters etc. in the label.

---

````
---
title: "example"
author: "X"
date: "2023-09-23"
output: pdf_document
---

\newcommand{\csubsubsection}[2]{
  \subsubsection{\texorpdfstring{\centering\emph{#1}}{#1}}\label{#2}
}

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

below after some sections....


\csubsubsection{Model applied: $lm(x \sim y,\mathrm{random} = \sim 1|A)$}{AppliedModel}
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. If you would not mind, could you please just explain briefly the meaning of using `$` symbol before lmer, the meaning of `mathrm`, and the final `{AppliedModel}`, what is it usful for?

Comment: @12666727b9 You seem to have some type of equation in your subsection title, so I wrapped it in `$...$` so that it will be set in math mode with correct spacing around the symbols etc. The `\mathrm` is to switch back to normal font for a correct kerning of `random`. The final `{AppliedModel}` is a second argument which will get used as label for your subsection. As I said in the answer, you should not use your whole subsection title as label.

Answer (score 1):

Unnecessarily complicated. You only need `### \centering ...`  or `### \hfil ...` for headers of a single line.

To reference the model, you can use just `[...]` but for safety and simplicity, better add a label (`### \centering ... {#label}`)  and then use `[your link text](#label)`

Only for the sake of completeness, a MWE to test hiding or not the model in table of contents, numbering it or not, with globally numbered or unnumbered headers:

---

[image: mwe]

---

The `MWE.Rmd`:

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: true
toc: true
linkcolor: blue
toccolor: magenta
---

# Section
##  Subsection
### \centering Model applied: \(lm(x \sim y,\mathrm{random} = \sim 1|A)\) { #bar}

The [model](#bar) is in page \pageref{bar} is. 
If `number_sections: false`  obviously cross-references 
to section numbers will be empty.

#### Paragraph
Bla bla ..

### \centering Model applied: \(lm(x \sim y,\mathrm{random} = \sim 1|A)\) {.unnumbered .unlisted  #foo}

The [Applied Model](#foo) in page   \pageref{foo} is unnumbered 
even with `number_sections: true` and not listed in ToC. 
In this case a cross-reference will point to the last 
numbered header (now the paragraph \ref{foo}).
```

Comment: Wow. Really  appreacited your solution

Comment: Hi. If it is possible l would like to know what you would suggest in case to add exactly after that section a flextable object and model it according to the page width that it is needed.

Comment: @12666727b9 My suggestion is read the documentacion of  `flextable`. I have zero experience  with this packages, but in a quick search  I found  the  fuction `witdh()` and  `fit_to_width()` that seem useful to set the width off the columns or the maximal width of the table in inches.